# Manage computer details post image

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vbscript

I've recently finished my 1st year of uni learning about programming basic information systems in VB.net. My current job involves managing special production computers for a live events company and I have come up with an improvement to help our computer set-up process, I have tried to code it but there are several elements that are getting me bogged down so I decided to start again seeking feedback first.

Currently when we re-image on of our playback computers (which happens to every machine at least every month) I have to manually set up all the computer details (such as Name, IP, Subnet, Windows license key) along with install the actual software (which is dependant on what show the computers will be doing next)

The computers currently have a very basic VB script that is in the startup task list which detects the computer name (if "MEDIAX" - which is the name given to the image and means the computer hasn't been configured) and tells the user what they need to do to get the computer going.

I am trying to expand on this concept so it pulls info from CSV files and then execute the setup for the user.

The first CSV file is for software
 - Software Name
 - location of vbs installation script (This is important as some
   software requires special intervention so the vbscript can be made
   for each installer and give the user instructions)
 - the location of a post install script (which can be just 0 if one
   isn't needed)

along with another CSV file that lists:

- Computer names
- Computer IP
- Computer Subnet
- Windows activation Key

This means that any average joe who is imaging the computer simply selects from drop down boxes what software they want and what computer they are setting up.

My program leading up to the final "execute changes" page works so you can list computers and select them and edit details and all that fanciness. Just I now need to work out how to get VB.net to make those changes.

currently I am trying to get my program to just execute batch files and VB scripts and pass in variables but I am having issues with it calling a batch or VBscrip that needs elevated permissions. I would like to avoid too much code split across different programs but I can't really see another option. I have attempted to name the computer using example code found on the web but these won't even let the debugger execute saying that it has "application manifest has the UiAccess attribute set to true"

I would post screenshots to give people a better idea on what I have so far but I apparently don't have enough Stack overflow 'street cred'

As this is just in the "personal project stage" where I aim to build my skills I am after some input on how I should be approaching this problem and building the solution from experienced people such as yourselves.